# Is this a statistical test ? what is the experimental unit? and how to treat dependency between observations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, independence, ab-test, marketing

I'm trying to understand which statistical test to use and what is my experimental unit?

The problem:
We have a budget algorithm that moves the budget between 10 different ad campaigns and tries to maximize the converted users given constraints for the group.
We want to compare two different versions of these budget allocation algorithms.
The targeted users were allocated randomly between algorithms A and B.
Algorithm A - Targets 10 campaigns with 50% of the users. each campaign targets different users in the 50%.
Algorithm B - Targets duplicated 10 campaigns with 50% of the users. Each campaign targets different users in the 50%.

The campaigns are identical between the groups just target different users (randomly allocated) and use a different algorithm.

Our experiment question is which algorithm gets us more conversions?

1. We are not sure if the single user is the experimental unit and we can use a proportion test or maybe the entire experiment is one experimental unit? and then no statistical test available.
2. If the single user is the experimental unit how do we treat the fact the users are not independent of each other in each group? If the algorithm moves money from one campaign to another it creates a dependency between the users of one campaign to another.[image]

Comment: I can't answer your specific questions, but not everything benefits from a statistical test. Why not simply choose the algorithm that gave the best conversion rate?

Comment: If users in A are paired with users in B

Comment: The users are randomly allocated between A and B.
arms A and B are independent in every sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not give enough information for a definitive answer.

Ordinarily, 'users' would be experimental units.
Depending on what response you record for each uses. If Yes/No to 'conversion', then you'd compare proportions of 'Yes's; if dollar amount or size of order, then maybe compare using a t or Wilcoxon test.

Also, you give no clue whether there is pairing between recipients of Algorithms A and B; if so, you'd have to use a paired test. In the examples below, I am assuming that data are not paired.

**Example 1 (Yes/No):**  If there were 87 'Yes's out of 1000 users from A, and 73 out of 950 users from B, then a `prop.test` in R would give
results as shown below. At the 5% level, there is no significant difference between proportions $0.087$ and $0.077$ of 'Yes's;
the P-value is $0.415 > 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
prop.test(c(87, 73), c(1000, 950), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality 
        of proportions without 
        continuity correction

data:  c(87, 73) out of c(1000, 950)
X-squared = 0.66741, df = 1, p-value = 0.414
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.01417267  0.03448846
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.08700000 0.07684211
```

**Example 2 (normally distributed dollar amounts):**
Suppose you have the following fictitious data.
At the 5% level, a Welch 2-sample t test finds a significant difference between observed average dollar amounts
\$300.64 and  \$326.93. The P-value (very near 0) is less than 5%.

```
set.seed(2021)
a = rnorm(1000, 300, 50)  # NORM(mean 300, sd 50)
b = rnorm( 950, 325, 40)  # NORM(mean 326, sd 40)

t.test(a, b)              # test null means =, vs not =

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = -12.652, df = 1888.6, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -30.36491 -22.21430
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 300.6376  326.9272
```

**Example 3 (non-normal ordinal data):** We use the same data as
in Example 2, but ignore that they are normally distributed.
Thus, we use a nonparametric Wilcoxon rank sum test to see
if 'locations' of responses from A and B are equal. Again here,
there is a significant difference in population locations (some
would say population medians) because of the P-value very near 0.

```
wilcox.test(a, b)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 325030, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

These are only three of many types of examples that might have been provided.

If you have data or can give more information about what kind of
data you anticipate, maybe the clues above will help you to provide
what is needed for a specific answer.

**Addendum on chi-squared per Comment:**

Using a $2\times 2$ table with `chisq.test` (omitting the Yates correction) gives the same result as `prop.test`.

```
A = c(87,913);  B = c(73, 877)
TBL = rbind(A,B)
TBL
  [,1] [,2]
A   87  913
B   73  877
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 0.66741, df = 1, p-value = 0.414
```

Comment: Thx for the answer BruceET. Conversion is a binary variable in our case. It's not a paired test.
Why the user is the experimental unit? Proportion test will answer the question "What algorithm gives us a better probability of user to convert"  which is not exactly what we are asking: "which algorithm brought us more conversions?".

Comment: Ordinarily a larger probability of conversion will lead to more conversions. If $p$ is the probability of conversion and $n=1000$ subjects, then the distribution of the number of conversions is $X\sim\mathsf{Binom}(n, p).$ and the expected number of conversions is $E(X) = np.$ // Anyhow, it seems that Example 1 fits your situation and that `prop.test` in R will work. Also, `prop.test` is equivalent to making a $2\times 2$ table (rows A/B cols Y/N) and doing a chi-squared test.

Comment: Thanks for additional information. // See Addendum for use of `chisq.test`. I prefer `prop.test` because the output for that gives more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers BruceET!